# Can I make a library from multiple targets?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to learn `cmake` and have started converting an old `make` project over to `cmake`. Here is a simplified version of the directory structure I now have:

```
CMakeLists.txt
  src/
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp
    core/
      CMakeLists.txt
      /sourcecode, other cmakes, etc.
  test/
    CMakeLists.txt
    someTest.cpp
```

Currently, in my root `CMakeLists.txt` file I simply have this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(all)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

What I wanted to do, was have a library created by `core/CMakeLists.txt` that can be used by both `src/CMakeLists.txt` to build the main executable, but also loaded by `test/CMakeLists` to build the unit tests.

So my `src/core/CMakeLists.txt` file currently looks sort of like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)                                             

project(core)                                                                   

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wpedantic -Wreorder -DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK ")

#some other directories in my core code:                                                          
add_subdirectory(display)                                                       
add_subdirectory(training)                                                      
add_subdirectory(utility)                                                       

#some packages I use...  
find_package(Boost 1.55.0                                                       
    COMPONENTS                                                                  
    log                                                                         
    program_options                                                             
    serialization                                                               
    thread                                                                      
    system                                                                      
    filesystem                                                                  
    REQUIRED)                                                                   

find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)                                                     
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)                                                   
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

include_directories(                                                            
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}                                                       
    ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})                                                      

target_link_libraries(core                                                                                                                           
    display                                                                     
    training                                                                    
    utility                                                                     
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}                                                          
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}                                                         
    ${GLUT_LIBRARY}                                                             
    ${OpenMP_LIBRARIES})
```

So the idea is that I now have a `core` target I can simply link against to run my tests, and everything should work. However, when I try to build `main`, for example, I get:

```
Cannot specify link libraries for target "core" which is not built by this
  project.
```

I thought this might be because `core` doesn't have a `add_library` command, but if I add `add_library(core)` I get this error:

```
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library core without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
```

But I don't *want* to add any source files; I just want this target to link the targets in the `core` directory and produce a target I can link against from `test`.

Clearly I'm missing some core knowledge here, either with `cmake` or the toolchain itself. Help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to create a **core** target without source files, you need to declare it like an **INTERFACE** target. So, try to add the following code to your `src/core/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0) # REQUIRED 3.x.x version                                             

project(core)                                                                   

...

# Here declare your core_interface target
add_library(core_interface INTERFACE)                                                   

target_link_libraries(core_interface INTERFACE                                                                                                                           
    display                                                                     
    training                                                                    
    utility                                                                     
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}                                                          
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}                                                         
    ${GLUT_LIBRARY}                                                             
    ${OpenMP_LIBRARIES})
```

As you can see, if you make this, you'll need to upgrade your CMake installed version.

Then, you'll build your tests or any executable, linking with this interface target directly:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main core_interface)
```